# Getting wrong output with cube root

Tags: math-mode

I am having some problem with the following code. It seems that the cube sign on my square root sign is a little out of place, and the first fraction under the square root is a little small. Looking for some help fixing these problems, thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$z_{0,1} = \sqrt[\leftroot{-3}\uproot{3}3]{-\tfrac{f}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{f^2}{4}+\frac{e^3}{27}}}$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Of course, the first fraction is quite small, since explicitly asked for  a `text` fraction (`\tfrac`).

Answer (score 2):

I would use these parameters, and avoid the `plain TeX` construction with `$$ $$`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ z_{0,1} = \sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}3]{-\frac{f}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{f^2}{4}+\frac{e^3}{27}}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why avoid $$ I have been using them for all mathematical notation?

Comment: It can lead to bad spacing and has some drawbacks. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: You can write a mathematical expresion inline, within the text using a pair of single dollar signs, such as `$ y = f(x) $`, but when you want to display a mathematical expression outside the text, is very comfortable to use the double pair of dollar signs, but it isn't a good choice in LaTeX because, as Bernard says, it lead a bad spacing. The best in my experience is to use the `equation` environment or another similar included in the [`amsmath` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).